# How Can I extend the layout in FaCuZ/laravel-theme?

Tags: laravel-5.8

I have a Laravel5.8 blog project. I want to use the Laravel Theme: ***FaCuZ/laravel-theme***. I didn't find any tutorial for it.
Does anyone knows how to achieve it in laravel5.8.

Comment: Just download it and apply it as other themes does.

Comment: After installing it, how this will work?